# BASH get data out of a markdown table

Tags: bash, markdown

I'm working with an application that outputs really pretty information. However, this gets in the way of actually using that information for automation.

```
Blah blah blah
Acting as user 'admin' on 'Bosh Lite Director'

+------------------+-----------+-------------+
| Name             | Versions  | Commit Hash |
+------------------+-----------+-------------+
| important-value  | 0+dev.27* | e5b99f85+   |
|                  | 1         | 3781cf3f+   |
| another-value    | 2         | 3781cf3f+   |
| and-another      | 0+dev.15  | 19c27248+   |
|                  | 0+dev.16  | 19c27248+   |
|                  | 0+dev.17  | 19c27248+   |
|                  | 0+dev.18  | a05a76b9+   |
|                  | 0+dev.19  | a05a76b9+   |
|                  | 0+dev.20  | a05a76b9+   |
|                  | 0+dev.21  | a05a76b9+   |
|                  | 0+dev.22  | a05a76b9+   |
|                  | 0+dev.23* | a05a76b9+   |
+------------------+-----------+-------------+
(*) Currently deployed
(+) Uncommitted changes

Releases total: 3
```

So out of this table I want to grab the latest version, or be able to get a list of the version numbers I can check against.

so getting the data for `important-value` would be `0+dev.27, 1` and then I could go through that list and see if a particular version was there.

What's a pretty consistent way to grab that information out of a table like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way in bash:

```
echo $YOUR_CONTENT | tr -d ' ' | cut -d "|" -f2,3 | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n|/,/g' |
     grep "important-value" | cut -d "|" -f2
```

result:

```
0+dev.27*,1
```